PDF does not display on mobile device within a modal
On PC it works correctly, but when I try it on mobile I only get a button with the text "Open" but when I press it nothing happens.
I've already tried it in several browsers and they all give the same result.
This is the function I use:
async function frmMostrar(idPDF){
    $(cargador__).attr('style', 'display: flex;');
    await fetch(`/obtenerInformeFinalDrive`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ idPDF: idPDF }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "X-CSRF-TOKEN": xcsrftoken_ },
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('No se pudo recuperar el PDF');
        }
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(responseBlob => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
            const pdfBlob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);

            const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.src = pdfUrl;
            iframe.height = '100%';
            iframe.width = '100%';

            if (!alertify.modal_informe_final) {
                alertify.dialog("modal_informe_final", function() {
                    return {
                        main: function(message) {
                            this.message = message;
                        },
                        prepare: function() {
                            this.setContent(this.message);
                        }
                    };
                });
            }
            const modal = alertify.modal_informe_final(iframe).set({ onclosing:function(){}}).set({title: 'Informe final'}).maximize();
            const modalContainer = modal.elements.modal;
            modalContainer.classList.add('modal_informe_final');
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(responseBlob);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al recuperar PDF:', error);
    });
    $(cargador__).attr('style', 'display: none;');
}

Movil :
enter image description here
PC:
enter image description here

Mobile browsers generally don't have built-in PDF rendering.  You have to invoke another renderer.  It should be giving you a choice.

note: you can check if inline PDF is supported using navigator.pdfViewerEnabled - if not, you need to either use something like Mozilla's pdfjs (which is cross browser) or deal with it some other way
